# PHP preg_match found string with no-specified characters

Tags: php, regex

I have Czech dictionary, with word per line, i need to get out only words with contains s,r,t,S,R,T and vowels, so i prepared regex

```
if(preg_match("/^[aeiyouAEIYOUáéěíýóúůÁÉĚÍÝÓÚŮsrtSRT]*$/", $currentLine))
```

but it matches words with characters "č,š,ž" too. Where is problem???

Comment: Umm, can you give some examplee so we can test?

Comment: Works 5in http://regex101.com/r/wE6vB0/1

Comment: Is your input UTF-8 ?

Comment: http://www.liberix.cz/doplnky/slovniky/ooo/dict-cs-2.oxt - libreoffice dictionary, download, rename to ZIP, extract cs_CZ.dic. Open as ISO 8859-2, save as UTF-8, php code here: http://jsfiddle.net/1hjzdm1s/

Comment: @SilentCry If I test your code with dict and echo the matches, I get [this list of words](http://pastebin.com/Wm9cxUbH) which seems to be fine.

Comment: So thx, I don't understand to problem on my side... Maybe php.ini or something like that.

Comment: Maybe there's an encoding difference between editor (where the pattern is written: Eg. editor set to UTF-8 and input ANSI/ASCII). But could not reproduce your issue this way either. Try `utf8_decode($pattern)`